# Perl - New Hash item with modified data, sourced from a feeder hash that sourced another entry, clobbers the first entry

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to add a hash entry and a new, updated hash entry that are sourced from the same feeder hash and original data.

However, when I update the data for the 2nd entry... it clobbers the original entry... even though that data wasn't changed... it can only have changed due to both being assigned from the same feeder hash entry.

Here's a sample subroutine from a test program that I created to test this issue - it uses Tk for output...

```
sub hash_issue {
    my %feeder = ();
    my %global = ();
    my %personal = ();

    my $key = 'John';
    my $new_key = 'Johnathan';

    $feeder{$key}{First_Name} = 'John';
    $feeder{$key}{Last_Name} = '';
    $feeder{$key}{Address} = '123 Main Street';
    $feeder{$key}{City} = 'Springfield';
    $feeder{$key}{State} = '';
    $feeder{$key}{Zip} = '';
    $feeder{$key}{Is_Registered} = 0;
    
    $global{$key} = $feeder{$key};
    $main->Output->Append("First Name = $global{$key}{First_Name}  Last Name = $global{$key}{Last_Name}  Address = $global{$key}{Address}  Registered = $global{$key}{Is_Registered}\r\n");
    $global{$new_key} = $feeder{$key};
    $global{$new_key}{First_Name} = $new_key;
    $global{$new_key}{Is_Registered} = 1;
    $main->Output->Append("First Name = $global{$key}{First_Name}  Last Name = $global{$key}{Last_Name}  Address = $global{$key}{Address}  Registered = $global{$key}{Is_Registered}\r\n");
    $main->Output->Append("First Name = $global{$new_key}{First_Name}  Last Name = $global{$new_key}{Last_Name}  Address = $global{$new_key}{Address}  Registered = $global{$new_key}{Is_Registered}\r\n");
}
```

Here's the output...

First Name = John  Last Name =   Address = 123 Main Street  Registered = 0

First Name = Johnathan  Last Name =   Address = 123 Main Street  Registered = 1

First Name = Johnathan  Last Name =   Address = 123 Main Street  Registered = 1

(Extra Lines added to clean the post...)

How can I modify this to keep from clobbering the original entry... The REAL code contains more key to the sub hash.

Comment: Please provide a runnable minimal example, see [mcve] for more information. This will help clarify you question.

Comment: I had provided a complete subroutine with the needed variables (Other than $log_file) defined as subroutine private variables.  And I did explain that I used Tk, helping to explain the nature of the Output statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
$global{$new_key} = $feeder{$key};
```

This only copies a reference. You need to clone your data if you want an actual copy.

```
use Clone qw( clone );
$global{$new_key} = clone( $feeder{$key} );
```

Comment: A shallow copy (`$global{$new_key} = { %{ $feeder{$key} };`) would also work here.

Answer (score 3):

Please investigate the following code snippet for compliance with your problem.

My understanding from your description is that you try to create new hash `%global` (with `$new_key` as a key) with copy of values of hash `%feeder` and then alter a few values in it.

NOTE: a declaration of `%global` variable inside subroutine somewhat confusing

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

hash_issue();

sub hash_issue {
    my(%feeder, %global);

    my $key = 'John';
    my $new_key = 'Johnathan';

    my @fields = (
                    'First_Name',
                    'Last_Name',
                    'Address',
                    'City',
                    'State',
                    'Zip',
                    'Is_Registered'
                 );
    my @values = (
                    'John',
                    '',
                    '123 Main Street',
                    'Springfield',
                    '',
                    '',
                    0
                 );

    @{$feeder{$key}}{@fields} = @values;

    @{$global{$new_key}}{@fields} = @{$feeder{$key}}{@fields};

    speak_out($key, \%feeder);
    speak_out($new_key, \%global);

    $global{$new_key}{First_Name} = $new_key;
    $global{$new_key}{Is_Registered} = 1;

    speak_out($new_key, \%global);
}

sub speak_out {
    my $key  = shift;
    my $data = shift;

    say "
        Key = $key
        ------------------------------------
        First Name = $data->{$key}{First_Name}
        Last Name  = $data->{$key}{Last_Name}
        Address    = $data->{$key}{Address}
        Registered = $data->{$key}{Is_Registered}
    ";
}
```

Output

```
        Key = John
        ------------------------------------
        First Name = John
        Last Name  =
        Address    = 123 Main Street
        Registered = 0


        Key = Johnathan
        ------------------------------------
        First Name = John
        Last Name  =
        Address    = 123 Main Street
        Registered = 0


        Key = Johnathan
        ------------------------------------
        First Name = Johnathan
        Last Name  =
        Address    = 123 Main Street
        Registered = 1
```

Reference: [Perl - Slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices)

Comment: The subroutine that I provided was for a specific test that I thought also might be more relatable than my real use case.  I called the other hash "global" because in the real case, I have more of an all-purpose/global hash and a specific hash.  As my use case maps the key_value pairs... I'd have to move the data to the array, make the first entry, modify the arrray and then add the modified hash entry... which is a bit more complex than I want to handle right now... but I DO like the ideas you presented in your snippet.  Thank you!